# How to implement FnMut which returns reference with lifetime parameter?

Tags: rust

I have third-party library with code like this:

```rust
pub struct Foo<T> { t: T }

impl<'a, T> Foo<T> where T: 'a + FnMut() -> &'a [u8] {
    pub fn from_callback(closure: T) -> Self {
        Foo { t: closure }
    }
}
```

It works fine with closure:

```
let buffer = vec![0; 100];
Foo::from_callback(move || &buffer)
```

however I want to return `Foo` from my function. Because of that I cannot use closure, so I have decided to use own struct which implements `FnMut`.

I have defined struct:

```
pub struct Func {
  buffer: Vec<u8>,
}
```

then implemented `FnMut` for it:

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]

impl FnMut<()> for Func {
  extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, _: ()) -> Self::Output {
    &self.buffer
  }
}
```

implementing `FnOnce` is then required:

```
impl FnOnce<()> for Func {
  type Output = &[u8];
                ^~~~  error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
  extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, _: ()) -> Self::Output {
    unimplemented!();
  }
}
```

But I don't know what to use as lifetime for reference in `Output`.

Comment: I will be happy if someone contradicts me, however I am afraid that this is something that would require HKT (Higher Ranked Types).

Answer (score 1):

@MatthieuM. is correct. This can't be done without higher-kinded types, and even if they were available, I'm not entirely sure that `Fn*` traits could be changed to support it.

The problem is, you want your function to return a slice of a vector inside this function. However, this would require `call_mut()` to have the following signature:

```
fn call_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, _: ()) -> Self::Output<'a>
```

The lifetime parameter is mandatory, because it is the only way to specify that the result of the function call will live exactly as long as the function itself. This would in turn require `Output` associated type to have a lifetime argument:

```
trait FnOnce<A> {
    type Output<'a>;
    ...
}
```

This is exactly what HKT would allow. However, I'm not sure that it would be possible to use HKT for functions. Remember, each `FnMut` is also `FnOnce`: if you have a function which can be called multiple times, then it could also be called one time. Naturally, results of `FnMut` and `FnOnce` should be equivalent. However, there is just no way to return borrowed data from `FnOnce` because it takes the function *by value*. In your case the vector would be moved to the function and, since the function returns a slice, not a vector, it will have nowhere to go and so it will be destroyed. Therefore, such change would require allowing some functions to be `FnMut`/`Fn` but not `FnOnce`; I'm not sure if this is desirable or even possible.

Comment: Shouldn't it be true that every usage of unboxed closure may be desugared into struct implementing `Fn(Once|Mut|)`?

Comment: It is true, but how it is related to your question?

Comment: Oh, I now see what you mean. I don't know the reason why by-move closures work in this case. Unboxed closures have deep support in the compiler, so maybe this is a part of the compiler magic. Anyway, manual implementation of `Fn` traits is feature-gated, so such problems are not entirely unexpected.

Comment: Because following code works as I expect: http://pastebin.com/gXZLYN84, so if I can get desugared version (and thus name of struct generated for closure), I can return `Foo<ClosureStruct>`.

Comment: @kriomant the code in the pastebin does not work on nightly (2016-05-06) https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c5a82b073a5944b9c3040c8206144b5f&version=nightly&backtrace=0

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by using a `trait` itself to express the would-be function.

```
trait CallbackTrait {
    fn call(&mut self) -> &[u8];
}

fn make_callback() -> impl CallbackTrait {
    struct MyData(Vec<u8>);
    impl CallbackTrait for MyData {
        fn call(&mut self) -> &[u8] { &self.0 }
    }
    MyData(vec![0; 100])
}
```

And, when you want it to be a bit more generically passed around, it can be boxed.

```
fn make_another_callback() -> Box<dyn MyCallback> {
    Box::new<make_callback()>
}
```

Seeing as **no API** expects any `Fn(Once|Mut|)` that returns something with the lifetime of a function itself, the problem itself is an issue of framing. A situation where you might expect to use this functionality can instead use a `trait` with a small change to the approach, with the added benefit of much more flexibility like requiring other `trait`s, or having multiple functions. As for why the language itself doesn't support this concept, @Vladimir Matveev has that explanation.